# it is an error to mix objects from different versions of msxml

Tags: xml, vba, dom, msxml

I'm using Excel VBA and trying to achieve the following:

1) Send a HTTP request and get a returned XML
2) Select some elements from the returned XML and add them to another XML DOM with the appendChild method.

I got runtime error "it is an error to mix objects from different versions of msxml".  I found a workaround but not sure why the error occurred and wondered if there's a more elegant way to solve it.

The code that was throwing error:

```
Dim sURL as String
Dim Http As Object
Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.SERVERXMLHTTP")
Dim xgetCSS As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xMember As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Dim nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

Http.Open "Post", sURL, False
Http.send (xgetCSS.XML)

Set nodes = Http.responseXML.SelectNodes("//return/css/members/member")

For Each xMember In nodes
    node.appendChild xMember
Next
```

The workaround:

```
Dim sURL as String
Dim Http As Object
Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.SERVERXMLHTTP")
Dim xgetCSS As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xMember As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Dim nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

Http.Open "Post", sURL, False
Http.send (xgetCSS.XML)

Set nodes = Http.responseXML.SelectNodes("//return/css/members/member")

For Each xMember In nodes
    xDoc.LoadXML xMember.XML
    node.appendChild xDoc.DocumentElement
Next
```

So basically, I took the content of the returned XML, create a new DOM doc, and use this newly created DOM doc to work around the "mixed version" problem.  But is there a better way?  Thanks!

Comment: What is the URL and xgetCSS.XML? To be able to debug having these or test versions would help.

Answer (score 0):

Not really very keen on posting answers I can't test but here goes.

In your top version you are using the response XML direct without aid of a XML parser. This [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/284856/prb-mixing-different-versions-of-msxml-dom-objects-is-not-recommended) describes your error as follows:

> **Cause**
>
> When you mix different versions of MSXML DOM objects in a DOM
> object's method call, the object from the differing version of the
> parser that is supplied as a required method parameter is treated as a
> foreign object.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> Reference and use objects implemented by a single version of the MSXML parser. Do not > mix different versions of DOM Objects when you program the MSXML DOM.

So, when using direct perhaps you are dealing with an object implemented by a different version of MSXML parser.

I thought you always needed to parse the response into an XML parser client side before exploring the DOM. This allows you to specify/control the version of parser throughout your code. It also allows you to `validateOnParse` and ensure xPath can be used for locating DOM elements.

I can't test but maybe something like as follows?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub HandleXML()
    Dim sURL As String, Http As Object, xgetCSS As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xMember As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Dim nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList, node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    
    Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.SERVERXMLHTTP")
    With Http
        .Open "Post", sURL, False
        .send xgetCSS.XML
    End With
    
    With xDoc
        .validateOnParse = True
        .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        .async = False

        If Not .LoadXML(Http.responseText) Then  '<==Not sure if you need Http.responseXML here as can't test
            Err.Raise .parseError.ErrorCode, , .parseError.reason
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    Set nodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("//return/css/members/member")

    For Each xMember In nodes
        node.appendChild xMember
    Next

End Sub
```

---

Some Microsoft [info on XML Dom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx).